# C#: How to create singleton instance for Azure ServiceBusSender without using DI framework

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm looking for an example for creating Singleton instance of "**ServiceBusSender**" without using any dependency injection or IoC framework.

I'm trying to send some messages to Azure ServiceBus Queue using "**ServiceBusClient.CreateSender(queueName)**".

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: All you need to do is instantiate it manually... open the nuget package's assembly in ILSpy or Object Browser to look for interfaces and implementations.

Comment: For the context, what's the reason you're looking for a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your call to ServiceBusClient.CreateSender inside a singleton class. Refer to [Create a Singleton Factory for a Class that takes parameters / arguements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141338/create-a-singleton-factory-for-a-class-that-takes-parameters-arguements) for more information on how to create singleton factory.